# How to increase the height of remoteview in android notification

Tags: android, android-layout, statusbar, android-notifications

I am trying to create a notification with custom RemoteView.But when displaying notification,bottom of the RemoteView is getting cropped.Only half of the remote view is visible in the notification.Could any one tell me about increasing the height of notification in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the style of the notification intent to bigstyle,

```
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this).setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(longText))
```

Comment: what if i want to use custom layout to notification

Comment: I suggested have implemented the same as you, but does it have a maximum height to display. Cause I have a big layout and the bottom of the element is getting cut.

Comment: @Sagar Patil, hi there. Have you found decision for your problem? I have the same trouble

Comment: I also have same problem.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, Notification height is limited to **256dp** on Android.  Views will be clipped at the bottom that exceed this height.  Second, to create a custom Big Notification layout, use RemoteViews like this:

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_icon)

    RemoteViews content = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.content);

    Notification notif = builder.build();
    notif.bigContentView = content;
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notif);
```

Comment: .bigContentView is deprecated, is there any way else to do this kind of thing?

Comment: Solved with this:
        `mBuilder.setCustomBigContentView(getComplexNotificationView());`

Notification.Builder has this method for setting bigContentView

Comment: @LuigiBlu  By using this If I expand the notification then only shows my customview otherwise doesn't show custom view. I want by default the custom view.